# How to remove null rows in when using union all in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

**How to remove null rows in when using union all in multiple tables**

```
declare @FromDate date='2018-05-01';
    declare @ToDate date='2018-05-10';

    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [SNO],t.MNO,MNAME ,isnull(sum(v1),0.00) as Balance,isnull(sum(v2),0.00) as CurrentPurchase,isnull(sum(v3),0.00) as Deduction
    from (select MNO, PendingDeduc as v1, NULL as v2, NULL as v3
          from tblProductPurchaseBalance where EntryDate between @FromDate and @ToDate union all
          select MNO, NULL as v1, TotalAmount, NULL as v3
          from tblMnoProductPurchase where PurchaseDate between @FromDate and @ToDate union all
          select MemNo as MNO, NULL as v1, NULL as v2, AAVIN
          from tblDeduction where EntryDate between @FromDate and @ToDate       
         ) t inner join TBLMEMBERS on t.MNO=TBLMEMBERS.MNO
    group by t.MNO,MNAME
    order by t.MNO
```

[Sample Data And Result I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkWr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use  `t.Balance > 0` in your where clause, as `Balance` is just a alias name to your column in select.

Instead you can write  `HAVING isnull(sum(v1),0.00) > 0` after `GROUP BY`.

You final query should look like following.

```
SELECT ..., isnull(sum(v1),0.00) Balance
FROM
(
 --Your internal query here
) T
GROUP BY t.MNO,MNAME
HAVING isnull(sum(v1),0.00) > 0
```

Another approach is to again wrap you entire query inside a table and put the condition. Like following query.

```
 select * from
 ( 
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [SNO],t.MNO,MNAME ,isnull(sum(v1),0.00) as Balance,isnull(sum(v2),0.00) as CurrentPurchase,isnull(sum(v3),0.00) as Deduction
    from (select MNO, PendingDeduc as v1, NULL as v2, NULL as v3
          from tblProductPurchaseBalance where EntryDate between @FromDate and @ToDate union all
          select MNO, NULL as v1, TotalAmount, NULL as v3
          from tblMnoProductPurchase where PurchaseDate between @FromDate and @ToDate union all
          select MemNo as MNO, NULL as v1, NULL as v2, AAVIN
          from tblDeduction where EntryDate between @FromDate and @ToDate       
         ) t inner join TBLMEMBERS on t.MNO=TBLMEMBERS.MNO
    group by t.MNO,MNAME
   )t
   where T.Balance > 0 OR T.CurrentPurchase > 0 OR T.Deduction > 0
   order by t.MNO
```

Comment: It's display first table data only. is it possible to apply and condition in having clause. I have used three tables. v1 is 1st and v2 is 2nd and v3 is 3rd. Am asking about & condition in having clause

Comment: Are you still getting the issue?

Comment: ya.still in stuck with that. not solved. where T.Balance > 0 AND T.CurrentPurchase > 0 AND T.Deduction > 0 i think pbm

Comment: What is the issue now? did you put condition like  "where T.Balance > 0 AND T.CurrentPurchase > 0 AND T.Deduction > 0"

Comment: after applying where T.Balance > 0 AND T.CurrentPurchase > 0 AND T.Deduction > 0. some rows r not displayed. not only zeros other rows also hide

Comment: change AND to OR.. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use any aggregate functions in your outer query as per desired result. It will solve your problem. For example like sum function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).